# Why does android studio warn me about generic array creation for typed entry

Tags: java, android, generics

I have an adapter in my android project which takes in a reusable map and for simplicity keeps an array of its data to use.

```
private Entry<String, String>[] mData;

public MyAdapter(@NonNull Map<String, String> data) {
    mData = (Entry<String, String>[]) data.entrySet().toArray();
}
```

Now I wanted to make it a little more efficient and get rid of the unchecked warning, so I changed to using a specific array type

```
mData = data.entrySet().toArray( new Entry<String, String>[ data.size() ] );
```

However the `new Entry<String, String>[ data.size() ]` part is now flagged   "*Generic array creation*" with no further information. **Why is this illegal?**

I understand that Java has Type erasure and that generics result in different types (such as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865417/about-generic-array-creation-in-java)), but the above line of code still seems like it should be legal to me.

Comment: Effective Java 2nd Ed Item 25 explains why generic array creation is illegal, with a concrete example.

Comment: In my mind the types specified here are only for compile time and the type should still be valid when erased because `toArray( new Entry<String, String>[ data.size() ] )` is just going to become `toArray( new Entry[ n ] ) ` which is no different to the unchecked cast. Is that completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this illegal?

Because arrays are covariant. Suppose you were able to compile the following code:

```
Entry<String, String>[] array = new Entry<String, String>[ isoMap.size() ];
Object[] objArray = array;

// Does not throw an ArrayStoreException.
objArray[0] = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));
String key = array[0].getKey();
```

At runtime, an `ArrayStoreException` would not be thrown by the assignment because `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` (the runtime type of `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer>`) is covariant with `Map.Entry` (the runtime type of `Entry<String, String>`) - but it would then fail with a `ClassCastException` when you try to execute the last line because they key is an `Integer`, not a `String`.

However, you now have to worry about *every* element potentially being of the wrong type - given a reference to a `Entry<String, String>[]`, you can't know exactly how the array was initialized or updated, so accessing any given element in the wrong way could result in a runtime exception.

(When I say "the wrong way", I am constrasting `String key = array[0].getKey()` with something like invoking something like `array[0].toString()` - all objects have a `toString()` method, so that would not attempt a cast).

The safest way to avoid such a situation is simply to make creation of generic arrays illegal.

Note that this is different from the case of non-generic-but-covariant arrays:

```
String[] array = new String[1];
Object[] objArray = array;
// Throws an ArrayStoreException.
objArray[0] = Integer.valueOf(0);
```

Because that assignment would throw an `ArrayStoreException`, a value of the wrong type can never be added to the array.

As such, although you still have to worry about an `ArrayStoreException` when trying to put a value into the array, you don't have to worry about `ClassCastException`s when reading a value from the array.

Comment: Thats a good explanation, but as you show in the first example - the runtime assignment is legal - so it could be allowed to compile, why is this any different from an unchecked cast which is merely a soft warning from the ide/compiler?

Comment: I suppose because unchecked casts at least require you to explicitly cast, so you're indicating that you know you are doing something potentially type-unsafe; however, the top example shows that you would be able to get runtime errors *without* casting, or doing anything else apparently unsafe.

Comment: Well I suppose that's as good as answer as any I can hope to get. It is a shame though; In providing the array to the toArray function in my example, I am trying to tell it this is how it should be cast so I don't like that it isn't possible

Comment: It's not clear why you need the array, though, at least from the code given. Storing `mData` as a `Map<String, String>` (or `LinkedHashMap<...>`, or `List<Entry<...>>` etc), taking a defensive copy of the parameter, would be type safe.

Comment: Yes I ended up doing that before this question was answered. I only wanted the array for the random access ability (for the adapter) which set and map don't offer